# How Can I store in a pandas's df the a webhook's results

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I could connect a webhook that I created and enabled in Python, and I'm using AWS lambda with the URL callback made in AWS API gateway. Which is all well connected.

But as far as I know, the the event triggered by the webhook just contains the column id and the row id but not the modified value of the cell. So I got stuck because I need to store in a df the row id and column id of the new value of the cell modified in the sheet because I will use that df to update deals in a CRM called pipe due to the organization I work for has the two platform connected.

So I wanted to know if some of you have been work with this issues so could help me to solve it in Python.

Thanks in advance.

I've tried to use the column id and row id to get the modified value but I couldn't.

Comment: What is the "the event triggered by the webhook"? Is something coming from an app? You also mention "column id and the row id" but you don't explain what these are or where they come from -- is it something relating to spreadsheets? Please Edit your question to add more details.